# Spring Tx error

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Existing transaction detected in JobRepository.
> Please fix this and try again (e.g. remove @Transactional annotations from client).
> ```

Please send any suggestions for the above error.
I'm using Spring Batch framework to read a csv and save it to a database.

Comment: Could we see the class(es) where you put your @Transactional annotation?

Answer (score 1):

If you execute `jobLauncher.run(job,jobParameters)` from *inside* an existing transaction, you'll get this error.  (the reason for this is around the way Spring Batch handles transactions to support data consistency with the execution...)

here are some ways around it;

- if you're using JTA, and your JTA Implementation supports it, annotated your calling method with `@Transactional(propogation=NOT_SUPPORTED)` - this will flag the transaction to 'suspend' on invoking this `run` method
- don't invoke the `run` method from within a transaction - if you're using Spring Integration, for example, you can use Spring Batch Integration's `JobLaunchingMessageHandler` in conjunction with a queue or taskexecutor channel

Comment: added the <property name="validateTransactionState" value="false"/>

Comment: sorry, I missed to update. After adding above line the error is resolved